# Router, Rout and Switch not working in my React website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a website with React, but my code is not working and i dont understand why..

I have this code in index.js, because I want my header to always be there.

> ```
>  const element = <h1>Header</h1>;  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
> ```

I have created a few components, and I have this code in my App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import {Home} from './Components/Home';
import {About} from './Components/About';
import {Contact} from './Components/Contact';
import {Resume} from './Components/Resume';
import {Photos} from './Components/Photos';
import {NoMatch} from './Components/NoMatch';


    class App extends Component {   
render(){
     return(
         <React.Fragment> <Router>   <switch>
        <Route  path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route  path="/about"  component={About} />
        <Route  path="/contact"  component={Contact} />
        <Route  path="/resume" component={Resume} />
        <Route  path="/photos" component={Photos} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />   
      </switch> 
        </Router>
          </React.Fragment>
        );   
    } 
}
```

And all my components looks like this now, just temporarly:

```
import React from 'react'

export const About = () => (
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    )
```

The problem is that i only see "Header" on all pages, and when i change the path to localhost../About, it does not show anything else but "Header".

Why is not my code working and the code in my components showing in the different paths?

I've used the npm create-react-app and uses visualstudiocode. Thank you for the help, much appreciated :)

Btw, im following a tutorial and it is working for him but not me for some reason...

Comment: Your webpage static or dynamic?

Comment: can you try remove 'exact' from 'path="/"'?

Answer (score 0):

The Switch needs to be with a capital letter 'S'

```
<Router> 
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
        <Route path="/photos" component={Photos} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />   
      </Switch> 
 </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn’t ‘switch’ be with a capital letter ( Switch )?

Comment: @Chary In your codesandox example persist an issue: take a look at `index.js` line No. 11, it should be like this - ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Answer (score 0):

Is `<switch>` with lower case on purpose? It should be `<Switch>`

Anyway, I would like to see your code in a code sandbox if it's not the problem

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/Kristinsh/kshweb/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You didn't render the App component. Put the header in a separate component and render it inside App. in index.js render the App instead of the header.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-platform-hww8n?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you so much :)